# Printing all files in a directory in Perl - will not work

Tags: linux, perl, directory

So I am new to Perl and trying to simply open a directory, and list all its files. When I run this very simple code below trying to print everything in /usr/bin it will not work, and no matter what I try I keep getting told 'Could not open /usr/bin: No such file or directory'.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$indir = "/usr/bin";

# read in all files from the directory
opendir (DIR, @indir) or die "Could not open $indir: $!\n";
while ($filename = readdir(DIR)) {
    print "$filename\n";
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: `@indir` should be `$indir`.

Comment: @Barmar you are a hero I cannot believe that was my error!

Comment: @RyanSaffer: Perl will tell you about silly errors like that. Always add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another place where the very basic troubleshooting step of `use strict;` and `use warnings;` has been omitted, and it would have told you exactly what was wrong.

```
Global symbol "@indir" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @indir"?)
```

Of course, you'd also have to fix a few other errors (e.g. `my $indir = '/usr/bin';`)

I would also suggest that readdir is not well suited for this job, and would tend to recommend `glob`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $indir = "/usr/bin";

# read in all files from the directory
foreach my $filename ( glob  "$indir/*" ) {
    print "$filename\n";
}
```

Note how this differs - it prints a full path to the file, and it omits certain things (like `.` and `..`) which is in my opinion, more *generally* useful. Not least because another really common error is to `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!`, forgetting that it's not in the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks! this is my first perl program so everything is all new to me